# trouble understanding shell control structures

Tags: macos, shell, csv

I'm writing a shell script to be run on mac osx terminal.
Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
list="../../data/FIXED_DATA/test_Games_Subjects.csv"
sed 1d $list | while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    if [ "$f4" != "NA" ]
    then
      echo "do stuff"
    fi
done < $list
```

test_Games_Subjects.csv is has a list of names and associated IDs, f4 is a long string of characters, unless it reads "NA". The file is saved as a "Windows Comma Separated (.csv) file. It was made with excel.

No matter what the value of f4, the body of the if statement is executed.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If your CSV file uses DOS line endings, then each line (and thus `f4`) ends with a carriage return, because `bash` assumes Unix line endings. `f4` might equal `NA\r`, but it will never equal simply `NA`.

Comment: An aside: your redirection after the while loop (`< $list`) overrides the one at the start (`sed 1d $list |`). Assuming you want to skip the first line, you can use `done < <(sed 1d "$list")` and remove the pipe before the while loop.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. Plugging "NA\r" into the if statement produces the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Benjimin you just saved me another question!

Comment: Actually, you'd need to use `[ "$f4" != $'NA/r' ]` -- without the `$' '` quoting form, `\r` is treated as a backslash followed by "r", rather than a carriage return. But I'd use `... while IFS=$',\r' read ...` instead, since it'll make it whether or not the file has carriage returns.

Comment: When I add \r to IFS it uses 'r' as a separator...

Comment: I just want this to compare the value in $f4 with the anticipated value of "NA" - the trouble is, there's some character trailing the $f4 version of "NA". So the solution that worked for me was to add the * to my comparison:

   ` if [[ "$f4" == NA* ]]`

Now, as long as the value in $f4 starts with NA the pattern will be matched. This will work for my needs because none of the other values start with NA... and I don't expect them to in the future (I hope!).

Is there some way I can get Bash to tell me what character is back there? I've tried /r, \r, \n, /n none of them work in the expression.